# How to apply Stadium & Mymatches filter together if both are selected in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, duplicates

I have a two Components called MatchesList.jsx & MatchListItem.jsx. In MatchList Component, all the matches list is shown which can be filtered through a MyMatches checkbox & Stadium wise which can be selected through a searchable dropdown. MatchListItem component is used only to render the  containing details of an individual match.

MatchesList.jsx ==>

```
class MatchesList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedMatches: [],
      matches: [],
      stadium_id: null,
      stadium_name: "",
      showPagination: true,
      currentPage: 2,
      per_page: 10,
      limit: 10,
      offset: 0,
      last_page: null,
      totalCount: null,
      stadiumsList: [],
      noMatchMessage: false,
    };
    this.getMatchesList = this.getMatchesList.bind(this);
    this.getStadiumsList = this.getStadiumsList.bind(this);
    this.getMyMatchesList = this.getMyMatchesList.bind(this);
  }

  getMyMatchesList() {
    const playerToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    axios
      .get("/api/me/matches", {
        headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${playerToken}` },
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response, "from mymatches");
        const stringResponse = JSON.stringify(response);
        const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(stringResponse);
        const stringData = JSON.stringify(parsedResponse.data);
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(stringData);

        if (parsedData.status === "Token is Expired") {
          localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
          this.props.history.push("/logout");
        }

        if (parsedData.status === true) {
          const stringMyMatchesArray = JSON.stringify(parsedData.player_matches);
          const parsedMyMatchesArray = JSON.parse(stringMyMatchesArray);
          this.setState({
            matches: parsedMyMatchesArray,
            totalCount: parsedMyMatchesArray.length,
            last_page: this.state.totalCount / this.state.per_page,
            noMatchMessage: false,
          });
        }

        if (parsedData.status === false) {
          this.setState({
            noMatchMessage: true,
          });
        }

        if (this.state.totalCount < this.state.limit) {
          this.setState({
            showPagination: false,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  getStadiumsList() {
    const playerToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

    axios
      .get("/api/stadiums", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `bearer ${playerToken}`,
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        const stringResponse = JSON.stringify(response);
        const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(stringResponse);
        const stringData = JSON.stringify(parsedResponse.data);
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(stringData);
        if (parsedData.status === "Token is Expired") {
          localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
          this.props.history.push("/logout");
        }

        const stringStadiums = JSON.stringify(parsedData.stadiums);
        const parsedStadiums = JSON.parse(stringStadiums);

        this.setState({
          stadiumsList: parsedStadiums,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  getMatchesList() {
    const playerToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    const { stadium_id } = this.state;
    axios
      .get("/api/matches", {
        headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${playerToken}` },
        params: { stadium_id: stadium_id },
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log("from MatchesList", response);
        const stringResponse = JSON.stringify(response);
        const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(stringResponse);
        const stringData = JSON.stringify(parsedResponse.data);
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(stringData);

        if (parsedData.status === "Token is Expired") {
          localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
          this.props.history.push("/logout");
        }

        if (parsedData.status === true) {
          const stringDataArray = JSON.stringify(parsedData.data);
          const parsedDataArray = JSON.parse(stringDataArray);
          console.log("from matchList", parsedDataArray);
          this.setState({
            matches: parsedDataArray,
            totalCount: parsedData.match_count,
            last_page: this.state.totalCount / this.state.per_page,
            noMatchMessage: false,
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            noMatchMessage: true,
            showPagination: false,
          });
        }

        if (this.state.totalCount < this.state.limit) {
          this.setState({
            showPagination: false,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("from MatchesList", error);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMatchesList();
    this.getStadiumsList();
  }

  handleStadiumSelect(stadiumInfo) {
    console.log("stadiumInfo", stadiumInfo);
    this.setState(
      {
        stadium_id: stadiumInfo.value,
        stadium_name: stadiumInfo.label,
      },
      () => {
        console.log("stadiumname", this.state.stadium_name);
        this.getMatchesList();
      },
    );

    this.setState({
      selectedMatches: [],
    });
  }

  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.setState(
      {
        currentPage: pageNumber,
        offset: (this.state.currentPage - 1) * this.state.per_page,
      },
      () => {
        this.getMatchesList();
      },
    );
  }

  handleCheckbox(e) {
    console.log(e.target.checked, "from handleCheckbox");
    console.log("stadium_name", this.state.stadium_name);
    if (e.target.checked === true) {
      this.getMyMatchesList();
    } else {
      this.getMatchesList();
      console.log(this.state);
    }

    this.setState({
      selectedMatches: [],
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { showPagination, matches, noMatchMessage, stadiumsList } = this.state;
    const stadiumOptions = stadiumsList.map((stadiumsList, index) => {
      return {
        label: stadiumsList.stadium_name,
        value: stadiumsList.id,
        key: index,
      };
    });

    return (
      <div className="teams-list">
        <HomeHeader />
        <div className="d-flex w-100">
          <HomeSidebar />
          <div className="main-body p-3 d-inline-block ">
            <div className="inner-page-section match-time-table">
              <div className="d-flex w-100 align-items-end">
                <div className="w-50">
                  <label className="custom-check-box">
                    My Matches
                    <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.handleCheckbox.bind(this)} />
                    <span className="checkmark" />
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="custom-chossen  w-50 ml-auto flex-column">
                  <label
                    className="control-label text-right"
                    style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 16 }}
                  >
                    Stadiums
                  </label>
                  <Select
                    className="basic-single "
                    classNamePrefix="select.."
                    // defaultValue={teamOptions[0]}
                    isSearchable={true}
                    name="stadium_id"
                    options={stadiumOptions}
                    value={stadiumOptions.value}
                    onChange={this.handleStadiumSelect.bind(this)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="match-table">
                <div className="m-fixe-title text-center font-weight-bolder">
                  <h2 className="news-box-title pl-4">Match Table</h2>
                </div>
                {noMatchMessage ? (
                  <div className="no-invites w-100 bg-white d-inline-block p-4 text-center">
                    <h3>No Match Found</h3>
                    <img
                      src="/images/no-match.jpg"
                      className="img-fulid"
                      style={{ width: 550, heighht: 550 }}
                    />
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <div className="table-responsive mt-3">
                    <table className="table table-image bg-white">
                      <tbody>
                        {matches.map((matches, index) => (
                          <MatchesListItem data={matches} key={index} />
                        ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                )}
                {showPagination && (
                  <div className="paginate w-100 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <Pagination
                      activePage={this.state.currentPage}
                      itemsCountPerPage={this.state.per_page}
                      firstPageText="FIRST"
                      lastPageText="LAST"
                      prevPageText={<i className="fa fa-angle-double-left" />}
                      nextPageText={<i className="fa fa-angle-double-right" />}
                      totalItemsCount={this.state.totalCount}
                      pageRangeDisplayed={this.state.last_page}
                      onChange={this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
                    />
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Code is working but how do i apply the functionality of showing both Mymatches & the matches in Stadium selected together without any duplicated values(if a match is appeared on My matches & held at the stadium which is selected than it should not appear twice in the resultant list).
Thank you for any help.

Comment: That's a very long component. I'd suggest refactoring getting your data into another function external to the component and filtering based on state within your component.

Comment: By the way, why are you doing a JSON.stringify + JSON.parse dance on every piece of your data?

Comment: @AKX Ok. That means i have to edit my original code. is there no method or function which can be applied to the existing code to get the required output. Thank you for replying.

Comment: By the way, why are you doing a JSON.stringify + JSON.parse dance on every piece of your data?  Ok. Is it not the way to do it. we have to do it only once?

Comment: I honestly didn't bother even reading through all of the component, since it's so long and convoluted. Sure, you could probably hack something together that removes duplicates, but that's probably not what you want in the long run.